# TypeError: 'Locator' object is not callable using .first() in Playwright

Tags: python, html, chromium, playwright, playwright-python

I have a button on a webpage which looks like this:

```html
<button rpl="" aria-controls="comment-children" aria-expanded="true" aria-label="Toggle Comment Thread" class="text-neutral-content-strong bg-neutral-background overflow-visible w-md h-md
button-small px-[var(--rem6)]
button-plain


icon
items-center justify-center
button inline-flex "> <!--?lit$747127195$--><!----><span class="flex items-center justify-center"> <!--?lit$747127195$--><span class="flex"><!--?lit$747127195$--><svg rpl="" fill="currentColor" height="16" icon-name="leave-outline" viewBox="0 0 20 20" width="16" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"> <!--?lit$747127195$--><!--?lit$747127195$--><path d="M14 10.625H6v-1.25h8v1.25ZM20 10a10 10 0 1 0-10 10 10.011 10.011 0 0 0 10-10Zm-1.25 0A8.75 8.75 0 1 1 10 1.25 8.76 8.76 0 0 1 18.75 10Z"></path><!--?--> </svg></span> <!--?lit$747127195$--> </span> <!--?lit$747127195$--><!--?--><!----><!----><!----> </button>
```

I want to press it with Playwright in my Python code. I wrote:

```
page.locator('button[aria-label="Toggle Comment Thread"]').first().click()
```

Sadly, it is giving me the error `TypeError: 'Locator' object is not callable`. When I don't use `first()`, it says

```
Error: Error: strict mode violation: locator("button[aria-label=\"Toggle Comment Thread\"]") resolved to 3 elements:
```

which is right, there are 3 of the buttons on the page. I just want to click the first one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `.first` rather than `.first()`:

```py
page.locator('button[aria-label="Toggle Comment Thread"]').first.click()
```

Runnable example:

```py
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright # 1.40.0

html = '<button aria-label="Toggle Comment Thread"></button>'

with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch()
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.set_content(html)
    page.locator('button[aria-label="Toggle Comment Thread"]').first.click()
    browser.close()
```

That said, `get_by_role` is preferred:

```py
page.get_by_role("button", name="Toggle Comment Thread").first.click()
```

And try to avoid `.first`; find a stricter way to uniquely identify the element (possibly using one of its other many properties) rather than relying on element ordering on the page, which is liable to change unexpectedly.